# .Net 6 Upgrade/.NetStandard 2.0/2.1 Upgrade

Tags: c#, upgrade, .net-6.0, .net-standard-2.0, .net-standard-2.1

I am trying to upgrade one of my .net framework app to .net 6 and it uses one of the web api project from a common solution. The web api project(c# class lib) in the common solution is .net fw 4.8 and is giving few errors as shown below which I am unable to find a fix for.

[image]

I have tried using nuget packages

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
Microsoft.AspNet.WebAPi.Core
Microsoft.AspNet.WebAPi.Client
```

It builds but some packages show the yellow exclamation when expanded under dependencies and the message states:
Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebAPi.Core 5.2.9 was restored using .net frmaework, version (they mention all version from 4.6 to 4.81) instead of the project traget framework .NetStandard,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Comment: .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6, not .NET Framework 4+2. It can't use .NET Framework libraries. `Microsoft.AspNet.WebAPi.Core` is a .NET Framework library that's not used by ASP.NET Core. The ASP.NET Core libraries are named `.AspNetCore.` instead of `.AspNet.`

Comment: So, your .net 6 project is referencing a .net fw 4.8 project in the same solution? I would not expect that to work painlessly. The solution I would use is to move all common types to a .net standard library that can be used from both .net 6 & .net fw 4.8.

Comment: ASP.NET Core is very different from ASP.NET, even for the MVC and Web API projects. It uses different packages, different serializers, different routing etc. There's no singleton HttpContext any more. And the configuration, logging, DI are *completely* different. You should start by creating some ASP.NET Core Web API projects  using the project templates to see how Web API works now, then create controllers that implement the same API as the old ones.

Comment: I have used more nuget packages and one of them was also Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc as I have mentioned in my question above. I am still left with the issues. Also in this project I have a BaseApiController which has 2 protected methods for creating an bad request http result for collection of error messages

Comment: There's no `web.config` any more either. Where will your application get its settings from? `I am still left with the issues.` that's because your old code is still trying to use .NET Framework classes. There's no ApiController in ASP.NET Core 6 or IHttpActionResult. Those are Framework types.

Comment: @JonasH No I was upgrading a .net fw project which was using a nuget package reference of one of our common solution project which was also in .net fw so I am having to update this first to .net standard 2.1

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes and I am changing it to ControllerBase but I still see issue with

Comment: I am now trying to resolve by looking for alternatives and stuck with one issue, if anyone can suggest: I have an if statement where I am checking if the content is MIME multipart content, the statement is if(request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent()) which is giving an error HttpContent does not contain definition for IsMimeMultipartContent and no accessible extension method could be found. Any suggestions please?

Comment: request is HttpRequestMessage